# Extract variable from numerical code based on digit location with R/Regex

Tags: r, tidyverse, extract

Ive been struggling to find a reliable and concise way to recode a variable that is a 4 digit numerical code that signifies some combination other variables, we can say binary for now.
Those variables are:

location: 1 = North, 2= South

 sex: 1= male, 2= female

 job: 1= driver, 2= construction

 income: 1= high, 2= low

For example, a variable of 1111 code means: North,male,driver,high

R code for data is below:

```
    library(tidyselect)
    library(tidyverse)
    library(dplyr)
    
    location <- c("North", "South")
    sex <- c("male", "female")
    job <- c("driver", "construction")
    income <- c("high, "low") 
    
    dt <- tibble(data= c(1112,1212,1122,1221))

# A tibble: 4 × 1
   data
  <dbl>
1  1112
2  1212
3  1133
4  1231
```

I want to recode this column to get the final output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 1
  data                          
  <chr>                         
1 North,male,driver,high        
2 North,female,driver,low       
3 North,male,construction,low   
4 North,female,construction,high
```

Ive tried various combinations of `str_extract` looking to use regex for digit position, followed by either `ifelse` or `case_when` attempts and it either doesnt work or is massively bulky and redundant for the real data set (there 4 digit code with up to 9 actual other characters per digit location)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could create a `list` of named vectors and then do a match

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
lst1 <- list(location = c(`1` = 'North', `2` = 'South'),
   sex = c(`1` = 'male', `2` = 'female'), job = c(`1` = 'driver', `2` = 'construction'), income = c(`1` = 'high', `2` = 'low'))
 dt %>% 
  separate(data, into = c('location', 'sex', 'job', 'income'),
       sep = "(?<=\\d)(?=\\d)") %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), ~ lst1[[cur_column()]][.x])) %>% 
   unite(data, everything(), sep = ",")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 1
  data                          
  <chr>                         
1 North,male,driver,low         
2 North,female,driver,low       
3 North,male,construction,low   
4 North,female,construction,high
```

Comment: That works very well thank you!- wondering if theres a way to additionally do this with a `case_when` function? It would be helpful if the named vectors and regex could be passed through `case_when` as there are a multitude of other variables in the real dataset that are similarly coded

Comment: @XFrost I would say this way would be more efficient compared to `case_when`

Comment: @XFrost I am not sure how you creating those objects in the global env.  i.e. `location`, `job` etc.  If these are already created in the global env, we could get those objects into a `list` i..e `mget(ls())`